# SQL Query: Unify Timezones

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-format, convert-tz

In my DB there is a date-time (slot_start) field. Unfortunately the entries are expressed in two different time zones.
For example: 2021-02-08T08:00:00+01:00 and 2021-02-08T07:00:00+00:00

Now I'm trying to list all entries in Central European Time (CET).

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT customer_nicename,
   service_name,
   CONVERT_TZ(slot_start,'+00:00','+00:00') AS Slot_Start,
   status
FROM reservations
WHERE status LIKE 'confirmed'
```

But one of the two time zones are expressed shifted by an hour.

I dont get any further - can somebody help me out?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here all looks great : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=219e3e7ffc511ee5c0f3eb65ff303d14
What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: Hi it is Version 5.7.28.

Comment: Hi, when choose version 5.7 I can not enter the data examples from your question as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=219e3e7ffc511ee5c0f3eb65ff303d14 Can you do it ?

Comment: No there is an error:  "Incorrect datetime value: '2021-02-08T08:00:00+01:00' for column 'slot_start' at row 1" coming up.

Comment: @VBoka thank you so far. Do you know any other SQL query to get the timezones converted?

Comment: Well how did you get that data in the column slot_start in your database ? Can you help me insert them in my small database on this link so I can try to help you...

Comment: Sorry, the error is  only on dbfiddle.uk not in my query showing up.[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=219e3e7ffc511ee5c0f3eb65ff303d14)

Comment: Imagine you have two columns like in my example and show me the way you are inserting data in your database ?

Comment: Well, unfortunately I don't know how the date-time values are getting inserted into the db. A wordpress booking plugin is doing the job.